# What is the subject of a sentence with "name, who..."?

Tags: subjects

> Name, who studies medicine, hopes to help a lot of people in the future.

If a sentence is like above, is the name or who the subject?

Answer (score 2):

> Name, who studies medicine, hopes to help a lot of people in the future.

*Name* is the subject.

*who studies medicine* is an appositive of the subject, and *who* is the relative pronoun introducing the appositive.

> An appositive is a noun or a noun phrase that sits next to another noun to rename it or to describe it in another way.

[https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/appositive_apposition.htm#:~:text=An%20appositive%20is%20a%20noun,round%20brackets](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/appositive_apposition.htm#:%7E:text=An%20appositive%20is%20a%20noun,round%20brackets))%2C%20or%20dashes

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as the subject of a sentence.

Well, many sentences do have just one clear subject, and the phrasing "subject of the sentence" is sensible in those cases.  On the other hand, there are sentences with subordinate clauses and sentences with no clause structure at all -- it doesn't make sense to talk about the subject of a *sentence* in those cases.

For example, the sentence "Hello." just contains a single interjection.  There's no such thing as the subject of the sentence "Hello."

There is such a thing as the subject of a clause.

> Name, who studies medicine, hopes to help a lot of people in the future.

There are two clauses here.  The subject of the matrix clause is "Name".  The subject of the subordinate clause is "who".

Both "Name" and "who" are subjects, and both are parts of this sentence.  Each deserves consideration, although we could say that "Name" deserves more.  This "who" is in a subordinate, supplemental clause.  This "Name" is in an independent matrix clause.

"Name" isn't the only subject of the sentence.  However, "Name" is the subject of the main clause of the sentence.

With this sentence, that's as close as you can get.